# which node gives quite strange result

Tags: node.js, linux

Perhaps this seems silly, but when I run `which node` today it gives me something quite different as

```
/home/hearen/xxx/xxx/node-v0.10.28/bin/node
```

instead of something as

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

However when I run `sudo which node`:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

I am wondering how this could happen?

#### My Silly Questions

- how `which command` works to locate the path for the *command*;
- which node exactly selected based on the path? how?
- in my case, how can I use `/usr/local/bin/node` instead of the current weird one `/home/hearen/xxx/xxx/node-v0.10.28/bin/node`? just resetting the path will do the trick?
- why `sudo which node` gives me the right result? anything I missed?

Any help will be appreciated :)

### More Details

#### nvm

```
$ nvm --version
0.33.0


$ nvm list
         v6.6.0
         v9.1.0
->     v10.10.0
         system
default -> 6.6.0 (-> v6.6.0)
node -> stable (-> v10.10.0) (default)
stable -> 10.10 (-> v10.10.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.16.0 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.15.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.15.1 (-> N/A)
```

#### echo $PATH

```
/home/hearen/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/oracle-jdk-1.8.0_121/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/node-v0.10.28/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/node-v0.10.28/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/mysql-5.6.39/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/yosolo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:/opt/mozjpeg/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/git-lfs-2.4.0:/home/hearen/XXX/WorkSpace/Develop/bin:/home/hearen/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/home/hearen/.local/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/oracle-jdk-1.8.0_121/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/node-v0.10.28/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/node-v0.10.28/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/mysql-5.6.39/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/yosolo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:/opt/mozjpeg/bin:/home/hearen/XXX/XXX/git-lfs-2.4.0:/home/hearen/XXX/WorkSpace/Develop/bin:/home/hearen/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/home/hearen/bin:/home/hearen/.local/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Check your path variable. Any chance you're using a node version manager (like nvm or nvs)?

Comment: @fardjad yes, I am using `nvm` as the updated question.

Comment: @jww Yes! You are absolutely right, but the first thing came to me is to ask help in SO where I found lots of brilliant people here. Sorry for the wrong move, I'll ask myself this question next time: **minimal example possible?** Thank you jww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way [**Node Version Manager**](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and similar software packages work is by putting a copy of [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) and a few wrapper scripts and/or [symlink](/questions/tagged/symlink)s in your user home directory (under `~/.nvm` by default) and prepending the directory containing those scripts to your **PATH** environment variable. That is usually done by modifying your shell startup script (i.e. `~/.bashrc` or other files depending on your selected shell and current configuration).

The reason it shows a different path when you run `which node` with **sudo** is that you most likely have **node.js** installed globally and the directory containing those wrapper scripts is not added to **root** user's PATH environment variable.

You can confirm this by comparing the output of the following commands:

`echo $PATH`

And

`sudo echo $PATH`

To use the globally installed version of node, you can remove the line that sources `nvm.sh` from your shell startup script (and logout and log back in - this will disable nvm permanently) or reset your PATH environment variable.